# convert excel model (input-calc-output) to another platform for gd

Tags: python, c#, vba, julia

I work in insurance as an actuary, and one thing we deal with is models, it usually involve bunch of input tables, then a calculation or projection process to produce certain output in interests.

It is usually more complex then usual excel reports you see in business world.

Now given the fast calc speed & effienciency in oher programming platform (C#, python, C++, Julia...etc)
I really want to use other platform to either

1. replicate the certain computational intensive process which usually takes 2-3 hrs as it go back and forth between bunch of excel sheets and doing an iterative process and find the solution
2. call or control the excel process

I understand python can control for part 2 using openpyxl , but for 1. which are the easiest to replicate with? here i meant easy to convert.

thanks many~

i am playing around python but did not expect can replicate the complex iteration process easily

Answer (score 1):

This question will almost certainly get closed as StackOverflow does not allow asking for recommended software.

There's an active actuary group in Julia, their website is here:

https://juliaactuary.org/